# regex for complex delimited string with multiple parse patterns

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have the following string:

```
def str='prop1: value1, prop2: value2;value3, prop3:"test:1234, test1:23;45, test2:34;34", prop4: "test1:66;77, 888"'
```

what i want to end up with is the following list of pairs

```
prop1: value1
prop2: value2;value3
prop3: test:1234, test1:23;45, test4:34;34
prop4: test, 66;77, 888
```

I figure if i can first parse and strip out props3 and 4, then i can simply split on comma for the rest of the string.  but having a problem with being able to get a match for prop 4

The following is the code and regex i have tried so far. commented out in the code are various regex i have tried but not able to extract the last prop4

```
  def str='prop1: value1, prop2: value2;value3, prop3:"test:1234, test1:23;45, test4:34;34", prop4: "test, 66;77, 888"'
  //def regex = /(\w+):"(.*)"[,\s$]/
  //def regex = /(\w+):"(.*)"[,|\s|$]/
  def regex = /(\w+):"(.*)"[,\s]|$/
  def m = (str =~ regex)
  (0..<m.count).each{
    println("${m[it][1]}=${m[it][2]}")
  }
```

This returns:

```
prop3=test:1234, test1:23;45, test2:34;34
null=null
```

what am i missing here?

(Also, is there away to do parse all this with just a single regex pass as opposed to my approach described above..regex first, then split)

Comment: Can the double-quoted strings contain escaped (or doubled, as in CSV) double quotes?  You can probably write a complex regex, but that might break with different input.  Do you have a formal definition of the input grammar?  This is one of those cases where regex might be inappropriate.  _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think_ “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  _Now they have two problems."_  -- [Jamie Zawinski]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basee on your give example data, following regex would work:

```bash
\b(\w+):\s*(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,\"]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wg4jb5/2)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\w+)`: Capture group #1 t match 1+ word characters
- `:`: Match a `:`
- `\s*`: 0 or more whitespaces
- `(`: Start capture group #2

  - `\"[^\"]*\"`: Match a quoted text
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^,\"]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `,` and `"`
- `)`: End capture group #2

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok to have different capturing groups for different matches then please try following regex. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWWzLh/1) for used regex.

```
(.*?),.*?\s(.*?),\s(.*?)"((?:.*?,){2}\s.*?)",\s(.*?:)\s"(.*?)"
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
(.*?)            ##Creating 1st capturing group using Lazy match.
,.*?\s           ##using lazy match till next occurrence of comma followed by again a lazy match till space occurrence.
(.*?)            ##Creating 2nd capturing group which does lazy match.
,\s              ##Till next occurrence of comma followed by a space.
(.*?)"           ##Creating 3rd capturing group just before next occurrence of " here.
(                ##Creating 4th capturing group here, which has:
  (?:.*?,){2}    ##In a non-capturing group matching till next occurrence of comma in Lazy match and matching 2 occurrences of it.
  \s.*?          ##Followed by a space and again a lazy match
)                ##Closing 4th capturing group here.
",\s             ##Matching ", followed by space here.
(.*?:)           ##Creating 5th capturing group with lazy match till next occurrence of : here.
\s"              ##Matching space followed by " here.
(.*?)            ##Creating 6th capturing group with a mazy match in it just before next occurrence of " here.
"                ##matching " here.
```

Comment: `def str` is not part of input text, it is groovy definition of variable `str`

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir, have changed solution now.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
(prop.+?):\s*(.+?)(?=, prop.+?:|$)
```

- `(prop.+?):\s*`, capture the text starting with *"prop"*, up to a `:`.
- `(.+?)(?=, prop.+?:|$)`, capture all text up to another *"prop"* *key*, or the end of the string, `$`.

In *Java* you would use the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes.

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
```

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(prop.+?):\\s*(.+?)(?=, prop.+?:|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
Map<String, String> map
    = m.results()
       .collect(groupingBy(x -> x.group(1),
                                mapping(x -> x.group(2),
                                             joining(";"))));
```

Output

```
{prop2=value2;value3, prop1=value1, prop4="test1:66;77, 888", prop3="test:1234, test1:23;45, test2:34;34"}
```